# Not able to arrange Pandas dataframe in a particular format

Tags: python, pandas

Following is my data frame

```
Actual      Expected
F00000191U  F00000191U
2022-09-30  2022-12-20
0.546437    0.546437638135
F00000191U  F00000191U
2022-09-30  2022-12-20
F00000191U  F00000191U
2022-09-30  2022-12-20
0.546437    0.517306000000000
F00000QAXU  F00000QAXU
2022-02-28  2022-07-31
E0USA00HCY  E0USA00HCY
0.864700    0.911518
F000016X81  F000016X81
0.446887    0.446887122753
F000016X81  F000016X81
0.446887    0.446887000000000
E0USA0073X  E0USA0073X
2023-03-07  2023-03-14
0.836902    0.993576
F00000SZIP  F00000SZIP
```

I wanted this to be arranged in the following format. The alphanumeric text is the entity ID and the date and decimal value below are related to that entity ID. It's just the actual and expected values of date and decimal value w.r.t that particular entity ID. I just wanted it to be in the horizontal manner as follows. [image: Expected output]

In the output, I am not getting my value column populated for any of my entity IDs using the following code.

```
def process(df):
    actual_entity = None
    actual_date = None
    actual_value = None
    expected_entity = None
    expected_date = None
    expected_value = None
    for i, row in df.iterrows():
        if isinstance(row[0], str) and row[0].startswith('F') or isinstance(row[0], str) and row[0].startswith('E'):
            if actual_entity or actual_date or actual_value:
                yield {
                    'Actual Entity ID': actual_entity,
                    'Actual start date': actual_date,
                    'Actual Value': actual_value,
                    'Expected Entity ID': expected_entity,
                    'Expected date': expected_date,
                    'Expected val': expected_value
                }
                actual_date = None
                actual_value = None
                expected_date = None
                expected_value = None
            actual_entity = row[0]
            expected_entity = row[1]
        elif isinstance(row[0], str) and re.fullmatch(r'\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}', row[0]):
            actual_date = row[0]
            expected_date = row[1]
        elif isinstance(row[0], float):
            actual_value = row[0]
            expected_value = row[1]
    yield {
        'Actual Entity ID': actual_entity,
        'Actual start date': actual_date,
        'Actual Value': actual_value,
        'Expected Entity ID': expected_entity,
        'Expected date': expected_date,
        'Expected val': expected_value
    }
```

The output I am getting is as follows.

[image: Actual output]

Answer (score 0):

You can use a custom [`pivot`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html), I assumed here that IDs are starting a new row and are of the format `LETTER-digits-LETTERS` (this can be tweaked if needed):

```
names = ['ID', 'Start date', 'Value']

# identify types of values
col = (df['Actual'].str.extract(r'((?:F|E)\d*)|(^\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}$)|(^\d+\.*\d*$)')
       .set_axis(names, axis=1).stack().index.get_level_values(1)
      )

# pivot
out = (df.assign(index=df.groupby(col).cumcount(),
                 col=col)
         .pivot(index='index', columns='col')
         .rename_axis(index=None)
       )

out.columns = out.columns.map('_'.join)

print(out)
```

Output:

```
    Actual_ID Actual_Start date Actual_Value Expected_ID Expected_Start date     Expected_Value
0  F00000191U        2022-09-30     0.546437  F00000191U          2022-12-20     0.546437638135
1  F00000191U        2022-09-30     0.546437  F00000191U          2022-12-20  0.517306000000000
2  F00000191U        2022-09-30     0.864700  F00000191U          2022-12-20           0.911518
3  F00000QAXU        2022-02-28     0.446887  F00000QAXU          2022-07-31     0.446887122753
4  E0USA00HCY        2023-03-07     0.446887  E0USA00HCY          2023-03-14  0.446887000000000
5  F000016X81               NaN     0.836902  F000016X81                 NaN           0.993576
6  F000016X81               NaN          NaN  F000016X81                 NaN                NaN
7  E0USA0073X               NaN          NaN  E0USA0073X                 NaN                NaN
8  F00000SZIP               NaN          NaN  F00000SZIP                 NaN                NaN
```

Reproducible input:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Actual': ['F00000191U', '2022-09-30', '0.546437', 'F00000191U', '2022-09-30', 'F00000191U', '2022-09-30', '0.546437', 'F00000QAXU', '2022-02-28', 'E0USA00HCY', '0.864700', 'F000016X81', '0.446887', 'F000016X81', '0.446887', 'E0USA0073X', '2023-03-07', '0.836902', 'F00000SZIP'],
                   'Expected': ['F00000191U', '2022-12-20', '0.546437638135', 'F00000191U', '2022-12-20', 'F00000191U', '2022-12-20', '0.517306000000000', 'F00000QAXU', '2022-07-31', 'E0USA00HCY', '0.911518', 'F000016X81', '0.446887122753', 'F000016X81', '0.446887000000000', 'E0USA0073X', '2023-03-14', '0.993576', 'F00000SZIP']})
```

Comment: I am getting the following error   raise ValueError("Index contains duplicate entries, cannot reshape")
ValueError: Index contains duplicate entries, cannot reshape

Comment: Can you provide a reproducible example for which it fails? It works well on the provided dataset. Make sure to provide a `DataFrame` constructor as it's the best way to ensure reproducibility.

Comment: I added my reproducible input, can you first make sure that the code is running well with it? If not, also indicate your pandas version

Comment: The data frame I gave you is just an illustration of the one I have. Mine is a huge data frame with almost 800 records. I shared only some records here. I am using Pandas version 1.1.5

Comment: OK, but can you try to identify a reproducible slice of it that triggers the error? It's important for debugging

Comment: It is failing on line pivot

Comment: Yes, I know, but I don't know why ;)

Comment: Finding it hard to find data frame slice for which it is failing.

Comment: Any way to provide the full dataset?

Comment: Can I attach an excel sheet here?

Comment: you can provide a link